# Как в PyCharm работать с регионом текста?

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, golang, pycharm, jetbrains

В Visual Studio в редакторах можно работать с регионами текста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Для этого надо зажать Alt+Shift и двигать курсор при помощи мышки или клавиш-стрелок.

Как также работать в редакторах JetBrains, например в PyCharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На случай, если у вас вдруг нет средней кнопки мыши:

[image: На случай, если у вас нет средней кнопки мыши]

Answer (score 0):

Средней кнопкой мыши при нажатии выделяем.

Answer (score 0):

В Windows версии работают клавиши Alt+Shift+Insert и средняя клавиша мыши:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]